# Floquet-Bloch solutions of the quasiperiodic Schrödinger equation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations

I am concerned about the Schrödinger equation

$-x''(t)+q(t)x(t)=Ex(t).$

Here, the potential $q$ is real and quasiperiodic with frequency vector $\omega$. That is, we let $T^d$ be the $d$-dimensional torus and $\omega=(\omega_1,\ldots, \omega_d)\in T^d$ with the $\{\omega_j\}$ rationally independent, and $q(t)=f(\omega_1t,\omega_2t,\ldots,\omega_d t)$ for some continuous $f:T^d\to\mathbb R$,

Equivalently, we may formulate this equation as a matrix equation instead,

$X'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
q(t)-E& 0
\end{pmatrix}X(t)$,

where $X(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1(t)& x_2(t)\\
x_1'(t)& x_2'(t)
\end{pmatrix}.$

There are two equivalent descriptions of a Floquet-Bloch solution, which I am having difficulty reconciling.

First, we say a solution of the form $x(t)=e^{kt}(p_1(t)+tp_2(t))$ is a Floquet-Bloch solution, where $k$ is a constant and $p_1, p_2$ are quasiperiodic functions with frequency vector $\omega$ or $\omega/2$.

Second, we say $X(t)=Y(\omega t/2)e^{At}$ is a Floquet-Bloch solution, where $A\in SL(2,R)$ and $Y:T^d\to GL(2,R)$.

I don't see why these two are the same thing?

Comment: It will help if you explain: a) what is a quasiperiodic function, and b) what is d? Your original problem had no $d$.

Comment: this is not some straightforward identity; the matrix $Y$ transforms $X=YZ$ into a new variable $Z$ that satisfies a differential equation with constant coefficients, $Z'=AZ$; if you search for "reducibility of Hill's equation" you can learn more about when this is possible.